# How to write a regex in java to check whether a string contains two chars space and three integers?

Tags: java, regex, string

I have a string `String myString = "abc,QWAB 123,cdef";`.

How to write regex to check whether my string has AB (space)123. I don't want to consider `QW`. Also number `123` will be one digit or two digit or three digit, Always it will not be three digit.

Please help.

Comment: http://www.regular-expressions.info/tutorial.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile( "AB \\d{1,3}" );
```

Comment: Works fine with pattern. But when i use `myString.matches("AB \\d{1,3}");` it's not working why??

Comment: This tests whether the entire String agrees with the regular expression. You might use ".*AB \\d{1,3}.*", i.e., match arbitrary characters before and after.

Answer (score 0):

```
^[^,]+,AB \d{1,3},.*$
```

Try this.This should do it.See demo.

https://regex101.com/r/gX5qF3/8

Answer (score 0):

Try something like:

```
String myString = "abc,QWAB 123,cdef";
if (myString.matches(".*AB [0-9]{1,3}.*")) {
    System.out.println("Yes it mateched");
} else {
    System.out.println("Hard luck");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This this:

```
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
 * Hello world!
 *
 */
public class App {

static String myString = "abc,QWAB 123,cdef";
static String abcPattern = "(AB[\\s]{1}\\d{1,3})";

public static void main(String[] args) {


    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(App.abcPattern, Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE);
    Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(myString);
    if (matcher.find()) {
        System.out.println(matcher.group());
    } else {
        System.out.println(" No mach found   ");
    }
}
```

}